# Code Review "ToDo" Follow Up Items

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, comments, todo

I am trying to institute code reviews at my company, and recently we had our first code review meeting.  During the meeting, several positive suggestions were made and I added `TODO` comments in my code for following up.

After reading suggestions on here on best practices for code reviews, I would like to follow up on all the items I corrected at the start of the next meeting.  Is there a way to add a similar type of comment to the code such as `FOLLOWUP` so that I can quickly highlight through those code segments in the next meeting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own comment tokens. This can be found under

Tools > Options >Environment > Task List > Comment tokens

The following link provides more info. They are geared towards Visual Studio 2005, but the same info works for Visual Studio 2010

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekwz6akh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zce12xx2%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be walking though the code in the actual meeting.  Each participant should have already looked at and reviewed the code prior to the meeting.  Thus, diff tools are all that are needed.  No need for comments in the code - only commit comments are necessary.

If you are first seeing code in a review meeting then you are doing it wrong and wasting time.

EDIT:

[I'd recommend this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0932633196)

Comment: I appreciate your critique on code reviews, although it is a little more broad of a conversation than what I was looking for with this question.  Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own tokens (such as "FOLLOWUP") to the token list: Menu `Tools - Options`, option `Environment / Task List`.